# Why does this query result in table scan when I add an OR clause?

Tags: sql, mariadb

The following query results in a table scan on table `e` (`StationEvents`) for ~250k rows.

```
  SELECT COUNT(e.Id)
  FROM `StationEvents` AS `e`
  LEFT JOIN `Keys` AS `t` ON `e`.`KeyId` = `t`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN Stations AS `t2` ON `e`.`StationId` = `t2`.`Id`
  WHERE (t2.Name like 'g%') or (t.name like 'g%')
```

However when I remove either the left side or right side of the `OR` clause, the query performs much better. For example if I remove the right side, it utilizes an index on `Stations` and only scans ~600 records. Why does adding the OR clause cause a complete table scan?

With just a single clause, it seems to scan the Stations index first and does "reverse" joins to get back to the requested result, which makes sense.

My expectation is that with the OR clause, it should scan the `Stations.Name` index, Scan the `Keys.Name` index and basically to join back to the StationEvents table for the selected `KeyId` and `StationIds` since these are the only relevant results. All tables in this join have foreign keys configured.

Am I misunderstanding something here? What is going on that requires a complete table scan?

Looking for an explanation, and possible ways to improve performance of this query. I'm using MariaDB 10.3.

Comment: `OR` is really hard to optimize.  Are you asking *why* something is happening or how to fix it?  If the latter, are the left joins really necessary?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm asking both. It seems obvious to me how this query could avoid a full table scan so I'm not sure why the query optimizer isn't doing it unless there is something obvious I'm missing. As for the left joins, the relations are optional. If KeyId is null I still want the record to show in the result is Stations.Name matches.

Comment: Those Where-condition turn the Outer joins into Inner. MySQL's optimizer used to be bad in recongizing this, so try switching to Inner joins instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try helping query optimizer with [`OR expansion`](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM (
  SELECT e.id
  FROM `StationEvents` AS `e`
  LEFT JOIN `Keys` AS `t` ON `e`.`KeyId` = `t`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN AspNetUsers AS `t0` ON `t`.`UserId` = `t0`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN StationStatuses AS `t1` ON `e`.`StatusId` = `t1`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN Stations AS `t2` ON `e`.`StationId` = `t2`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN Regions AS `t3` ON `t2`.`RegionId` = `t3`.`Id`
  WHERE (t2.Name like 't%') 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.id
  FROM `StationEvents` AS `e`
  LEFT JOIN `Keys` AS `t` ON `e`.`KeyId` = `t`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN AspNetUsers AS `t0` ON `t`.`UserId` = `t0`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN StationStatuses AS `t1` ON `e`.`StatusId` = `t1`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN Stations AS `t2` ON `e`.`StationId` = `t2`.`Id`
  LEFT JOIN Regions AS `t3` ON `t2`.`RegionId` = `t3`.`Id`
  WHERE (t2.Name like 'g%') 
) sub;
```

Comment: `UNION DISTINCT` would be slower, but you might need it if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `StationEvents` AS `e`
            JOIN  `Keys` AS `t`  ON `e`.`KeyId` = `t`.`Id`
            WHERE  (t.Name like 'g%') 
    ) + 
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `StationEvents` AS `e`
            JOIN  Stations AS `t2`  ON `e`.`StationId` = `t2`.`Id`
            WHERE  (t2.Name like 'g%') 
    ) AS the_count;
```

Notes:

- Notice how a one-column, one-row `SELECT` can be used as an expression (with parens).
- `COUNT(*)` is the usual pattern.
- `LEFT` is useless since you are demanding a match on the 'right' table.
- A potential flaw:  An Event with g% in both t and t2 would be counted twice.

And you need these indexes:

```
On `t` and `t2`:  INDEX(Name, Id)
On StationEvents:  INDEX(StationId), INDEX(KeyId)
```

Possibly this would give you the same answer?

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `Keys` AS `t`  ON `e`.`KeyId` = `t`.`Id`
            WHERE  (t.Name like 'g%') 
    ) + 
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  Stations AS `t2`  ON `e`.`StationId` = `t2`.`Id`
            WHERE  (t2.Name like 'g%') 
    ) AS the_count;
```